# Magento 1.9.2.3 won't send order confirmation email based on shipping/payment method

Tags: magento-1.9, order-email

After upgrading a magento website from 1.9.0.x to 1.9.2.2/3 Magento has stopped sending the order confirmation email when a customer picks anything but the icepay (iDeal) payment option. The other payment options are banktransfer, free shipping (used as an option to pay in their physical store) and cash on delivery.

The cron is configured properly and the core_email_queue table is empty, and when send from the backend it also sends out the email. I have placed some logging in the email process and it seems it never actually gets to trying to send anything even though Magento claims it has send the email.

We are also using mandrill to send email and the mandrill logs are also empty, there are no warnings/exeptions related to the email process in any of the log files either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually managed to find the culprit, it was a incompatibility between a modified order.php file in the core made by one of my predecessors. Obviously I undid most of this work and made a override for the function that needed to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

After Magento 1.9 the order confirmation emails are not sent during checkout anymore and instead are being sent with the cron. Make sure your Cron is working (you can check the cron logs /var/log/cron).

Also make sure Magento cron is running every five minutes. You should see something like this in Crontab (in your server):

*/5 * * * * /public_html/cron.sh